# How to make sure whenever User is updated or created a contact is too?

Tags: apex, community

I'm new to salesforce so please don't kill me. I'm working on setting up a communities site with an external facing registration.

When a user registers, a contact is automatically created. I'm not sure where the code for this is. I'm just trying to update extra fields automatically when that user is created or if the user information is updated. This is my code I have in the CommunitiesSelfRegController.apxc. A contact is created but most of the fields are empty.

```
 /**
 * An apex page controller that supports self registration of users in communities that allow self registration
 */
public class CommunitiesSelfRegController {
    
    
    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    
    
    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {
        String expid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('expid');            
        if (expId != null) {
            Site.setExperienceId(expId); 
        }    
    }
    
    private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

    public PageReference registerUser() {
    
           // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
        if (!isValidPassword()) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        }    

        String profileId = null; // To be filled in by customer.
        String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
        String accountId = ''; // To be filled in by customer.
        String userName = email;
       
        
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = userName;
        u.Email = email;
        u.FirstName = firstName;
        u.LastName = lastName;
        u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
        u.ProfileId = profileId;
        
    
          
        

        
        String userId;
        
        try {
            userId = Site.createExternalUser(u, accountId, password);
        } catch(Site.ExternalUserCreateException ex) {
            List<String> errors = ex.getDisplayMessages();
            for (String error : errors)  {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, error));
            }
            
            // This message is used for debugging. Do not display this in the UI to the end user.
            // It has the information around why the user creation failed.
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        
        //I ADDED THIS
         try{
            
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.FirstName = u.FirstName;
            c.LastName = u.LastName;
            c.Verified__c = false;
            c.Username__c = userName;
            c.AlternateEmail1__c = communityNickname;
            c.Citizenship__c = u.Citizenship__c;
            c.Organization__c = u.Organization__C; 
            c.Company__c = u.Organization__C;
            
            insert c;
            update c;
            
        } catch (DmlException e){
            System.debug('A DML exception has occured: ' +
                        e.getMessage());
            
        }
    
        
        //Authentification
        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(userName, password, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startURL'));
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For communities a contact should be created before the user as the community user is linked to the contact record, .

Comment: I ended up using the process builder and created a process that creates a contact whenever a user is created. Now whenever a user is created two contacts are created. Do you know of away around this ? Or will I just have to find something to automatically merge the duplicate contacts. Or if the contact is created before the user: what i need to do is add a master-detail relationship between user and contact and figure out some way to update the contact everytime the user is created?